# Form validation for phone and zip code

Tags: jquery

Hi am trying to do form validation for zip code and phone number its not happening.
For code http://jsfiddle.net/raghu_koppal/CT5Y2/

Comment: If the only problem is with the zip and phone, remove all the stuff that isn't related.

Comment: I need that code for other thing

Comment: Yeah, but we don't--when asking a question it's helpful to isolate the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is too much wrong to explain it all but I hope this helps. You have this right now:

```
function () {
   objectKey: {
       a: 0'
   }
}
```

but that just doesn't work in JavaScript. You are mixing the function block and object notation `{}`

Comment: Now i isolated the code http://jsfiddle.net/raghu_koppal/CT5Y2/, now even email validation also not happening.